# ¿Cómo visualizar un archivo pdf alojado en un servidor ftp al momento de dar click en un boton en html?

Tags: php, ftp

Tengo este código, pero me gustaría que se ejecutara al momento de darle click a un botón    en un table html

```
  `<?php 

    $mi_pdf = fopen ("ftp://usuario:acceso@ave-l.com/BLABLA/ActaCons.pdf", "r");
    if (!$mi_pdf) {
        echo "<p>No puedo abrir el archivo para lectura</p>";
        exit;
    }

    header('Content-type: application/pdf');


    fpassthru($mi_pdf);  
    fclose ($archivo);
    ?>`
```

Esto ya me lo muestra si lo ejecuto directamente en un formulario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si incuyes este codigo en un archivo `pdfview.php`. En este caso usando un parametro `archivo`, de manera que te permita abrir distintos archivos pasando solo el nombre.

**pdfview.php**

```
<?php 

$archivo=$_GET["archivo"];
if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.pdf$/', $archivo)){
   echo "<p>Nombre de archivo invalido</p>";
   exit;
}
$mi_pdf = fopen ("ftp://usuario:acceso@ave-l.com/BLABLA/$archivo", "r");
if (!$mi_pdf) {
    echo "<p>No puedo abrir el archivo para lectura</p>";
    exit;
}

header('Content-type: application/pdf');


fpassthru($mi_pdf);  
fclose ($archivo);
?>
```

Puedes llamarlo desde el html con un link directo

```
<a href="pdfview.php?archivo=ActaCons.pdf" target="_blank" >Abrir pdf</a>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me ha funcionado

Comment: Genial! si la respuesta soluciona tu problema márcala como aceptada, o si queda alguna duda, consulta lo que desees.

Comment: Gracias amigo, de hecho no sé si me puedas orientar de como obtener la url actual del archivo que se sube a través de un formulario al servidor ftp.

Comment: Si el FTP esta en el mismo servidor que el sitio web, probablemente sea una URL relativa a esta, si los archivos se guardan en una subcarpeta del mismo sitio, de otro modo puede que no haya una ruta directa. Que servidor/proveedor/hosting estas usando?

Comment: De hecho por ahora lo estoy probando de manera local, estoy enviando de mí local al servidor ftp

Comment: uploadFTP("ave-la.com", "usuario", "acceso", "***", "BLABLA/ejemplo" con esa linea mando a traer mi función para subir el archivo al servidor, en donde estan los astericos pongo directamente una url, pero lo que quiero es que cada vez que se suba un archivo atrape la url de forma automatica